# Need assistance with a "Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'" error with foreach

Tags: c#, string, foreach, char

I'm sorry to be one of those who just ask questions, but I can't do much more until I'm much better at the language.

I'm trying to make a program for a friend of mine that plays this game. I don't play it much, personally, but he's staff on a server, and said that he uses skype to check people for hacks and illegal mods. I've been working on a program for him which will display the directory specified in a ListView for now, until I get it working so I can send it through SMTP or ftp.

Anyway, here's the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string files = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\.minecraft";
    foreach (string file in files)
    {

        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
        item.Tag = file;

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store a string with a file path in it here:

```
string files =
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\.minecraft";
```

And then iterate over the collection of characters in that string here (not what you intended), and then attempt to store each character in a string called "file".

```
foreach (string file in files)
```

What you want is to get files in a particular directory by using `Directory.GetFiles()`:

```
var minecraftDirectory =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".minecraft");

var files = Directory.GetFiles(minecraftDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I guess I had the wrong idea of foreach.

Comment: @GrantWinney Okay. Thanks for clearing that up. I've got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `GetFolderPath` returns a string.  You are then iterating through all of the parts of that string, i.e. the characters.  You are then attempting to put that in a string called `file`.  The compiler complains because `file` is a string, not a character.

In other words, `GetFolderPath` is returning something like "c:/Files/MoreFiles", while you put in `files`.  If you iterate through that, you will get 'c', then ':', then '/', then 'F', an so on.  You are attempting to assign this to a string called "file".  I suspect that's not what you are meaning to do.

It looks like you are missing a call, something that takes a file path (in a string) and returns a list of files which you can then iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.GetFolderPath` returns a string value.  A string is simply an Enumeration of `char`. So when you call

```
foreach(string file in files)
```

an error will be thrown, as `files` is actually just a string.

You might want to look into `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, "files" is a string.
When you get to the "foreach(string file in files)" the foreach is trying to break up the "files" into chars, but you are forcing it to be a string (string file).

check the documentation for Environment.GetFolderPath method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx

I get the feeling that you think this does something other than what you think it should.